# SSRS 2008 TextBox Borders Apply to single textbox

Tags: reporting-services, textbox

I am having a problem placing a border around a single TextBox. For some reason when I put a border around it, SSRS Applies the border to plenty of other TextBoxes in the same area.

I have a TextBox that is part of a Group That is part of Tablix. I am doing the following

1. Right clicking the TextBox
2. Clicking TextBox Properties
3. Clicking Border
4. Clicking the outline preset / manually clicking each border in the preview.
5. Clicking OK.

After I do this, the border style is applied to any TextBox this TextBox I right clicked on touches.

I thought it might have something to do with the TextBox being in the group, so as an experiment, I got rid of the borders and set just the back color. That worked as expected. - Just the single TextBox had the back color.

This doesn't make any sense. Why aren't borders being applied to the single TextBox?

Comment: Make sure You select textBox not cell in tablix.If I good understand You, You have that structure tablix->group->cell->textBox yes?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I am pretty sure I am selecting a TextBox, because I click the option "TextBox Properties". Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

Today, during my search I saw your question as I was having the same problem.
I solved this problem for myself and now I am submitting an answer here so that others can use it.

Follow these steps:

1. Click on TextBox to which you have to give boarder.
2. Then, go to the *Property Sheet* which is on the right side of your IDE window. It will show all properties of the selected textbox.
3. Change *Border* property value in the Property Sheet
4. Now, you will see that the *Border* value(s) you specified in the Property Sheet has been applied only to the selected textbox, not to other text boxes.

Hope it will work for others just like it worked for me.